# Will Windows 10 wipe my PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I understand there are a few questions related to this topic which is why I don't think it's duplicate, and that there is one directly addressing it. I am still extremely paranoid about this, and would still like to let you guys know how **EXACTLY** how I did it, since the process might be different from the other questions.

I believe the upgrade process is the same for both Windows 7 and 8.1 since I have PCs running both of those OSs that I would like to upgrade.

I didn't install other updates before I decided to upgrade to Windows 10.

Then I went to [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and I downloaded the 64-bit tool listed on that site.

Afterwards, I run the media creation tool.
[image]

It leads to the above image.

Will this program
A) download AND install
or 
B) download OR install?

Best case scenario it downloads and waits for me to give it the ok before installing.

When I give it the ok and it finishes, will the result be a WIPED computer or will all my personal documents/files all be there?

Comment: You should have your backups up to date and at hand, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first do the upgrade to Windows 10, it will not wipe your computer.

After Windows 10 is installed, you then have the option to perform a **reset**. That *will* wipe your computer.

Comment: So simply put, when I upgrade, and i get to the new Windows 10 desktop, all my stuff will be there, and there will be a pop-up/dialog that will give the option of a reset but i dont have to click that?

Comment: You keep your programs and files. There won't be a popup right after, there's just an option to reset in Settings if you go look for it.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - No;  Unless you perform a Reset, specifically, everything currently installed will transfer.  The potential duplicate answers all of your questions.

Comment: @Ramhound I suppose it does. Well marked, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Upgrade this PC now" option will download and start the installation configuration process once the update is downloaded. If you choose to not upgrade after it is downloaded, the data will be deleted and you will have to download everything again. You will be given the option of saving your programs + files, your files only or nothing at all. Note that if the program decides to run the upgrade in a language different from your system language (which is not a choice you get to directly influence), you will be forced to lose your programs or abort.

If you choose the "Create installation media" option, you will get a disk image (mountable with software such as Daemon Tools) or a USB drive with the installation files on it, which you can use to upgrade or perform a clean install on the current or any other compatible PC. You will get your choice of Windows edition (Home, Pro, etc), language and architecture (x64, x86 or both).

I recommend the second option, as multilingual users will not have to deal with the possibility of losing their programs if the updater decides to download the wrong language version of Windows, and you will be able to install the image on other PCs as well as restart between downloading the image and installing it.